# Update a div when value of an expression changes

Tags: angularjs

I am building a website using angularjs.
I have certain content-specific tabs i.e. they have their own content. When a tab is clicked, only its content is visible. Each tab has been given an ID in the controller.
I want to monitor the change in the tab ID and accordingly change the content of the tab. How do I do it?

I have read about `ng-bind`. It replaces the content of a specified div with the result of the expression provided, when that expression changes. In other words, it monitors the expression and updates the div with the result of that expression.

I want similar functionality, but I don't want the content of the div to be replaced by that expression( i.e. tab ID in my case). I just want the div to be updated with some other content that I load within `md-tab-body`.

Is there any directive for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can reference a property on your controller's $scope (or the controller itself, if using 'controller as' syntax). Then angular will automatically $watch that property for changes and update the view automatically.

Controller

```
$scope.tabContent = 'Some text content';
```

--

HTML

```
<div>{{tabContent}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ng-include directive. Something like below:

```
<div ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
    <div ng-include src="tab.src" ></div>
</div>
```

Where tabs can be an array of objects

```
    $scope.tabs=[{
     id: 'tab1',
     src: 'content1' // tab1 content
    },{
     id: 'tab2',
     src: 'content2' // tab2 content
    }
     ... 
    ]
```